# Why is this index out of range?

Tags: python

So I basically I want this to loop three times, as you can see I have choices = 0,1,2 and for `m` in range 3 so this should loop three times, first being for choice 0 then for choice 1 then for choice two. So why is this out of range?

Pythons exact error return:

```
choices[r]=p.nextInt()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

please ignore `p.next` as this is how we must write it at uni as we have our own module.

Here is my code

```
cities=["Coventry", "Birmingham", "Wolverhampton", "Leicester"]
distances=[
    [0,25,33,24],
    [25,0,17,42],
    [33,17,0,54],
    [24,42,54,0]]

def distancesthree():
    choices=[0,1,2] 
    for m in range(3): #This will loop three times!
        for r in range(len(cities)):
            p.write ("%d : %s\n" %(r, cities[r]))
        p.write("\nEnter city number %d: \n"%(m+1))
        choices[r]=p.nextInt()
```

Comment: Iteration by index is a recipe for disaster - Python is designed for iteration by value. It's faster, more flexible, easier to read, and you don't ever get index errors.

Comment: What the heck is `p`? It has a `nextInt` method...? Is it some Python implementation of `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: (It can't be exactly `Scanner` because it has `write`. Nevertheless, I'm curious if this is some interaction helper library that you're asked to use. It looks possibly nicer, though less Pythonic, than `raw_input`.)

Comment: That's what happens when you use single-letter names all over the place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you've used a wrong variable - may be you wanted to write `m` instead of `r`?

```
choices[m]=p.nextInt()
```

Comment: @ilius agreed, variable names should be meaningful. That's alos prevents of creating redundant variables - you just have to think about name first :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you use single-letter names all over the place...
`r` in the last line should be replace by `m`

But I edited your code to show you how it should have been written.

```
cities = ("Coventry", "Birmingham", "Wolverhampton", "Leicester")
distances = [
    [0, 25, 33, 24],
    [25, 0, 17, 42],
    [33, 17, 0, 54],
    [24, 42, 54, 0],
]

def chooseDistances():
    choices = [0, 1, 2] 
    for choiceIndex in range(3):
        for cityIndex, cityName in enumerate(cities):
            p.write("%d : %s\n"%(cityIndex, cityName))
        p.write("\nEnter city number %d: \n"%(step+1))
        choices[choiceIndex] = p.nextInt()
```

Then you will never use cityIndex for choices, or choiceIndex for cities...

Answer (score 0):

After the `for r in range(len(cities)):`, `r` will be `3` because that is the last item in the list of `range(len(cities))`.

Thus, when you do `choices[r]`, you are trying to do `choices[3]`, but the list only goes up to index 2.

Maybe you meant `choices[r-1]`? Or to even say `for r in range(len(cities) - 1):`? Or even `choices[m]`?

Comment: Thank you Haidro, you're spot on!